# What am I doing wrong when trying to plot two numpy arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I'm attempting to plot:
`x` and `y` values on a `ax.loglog` plot but am receiving the following error:

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4000,) and (1,)`

I have a list of numpy arrays called `holders`, where:

```
len(holders[0]) == 4000
holders[0].shape == (4000,)
type(holders[0]) == <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And I have a numpy array of frequency bins called `fax`, where:

```
len(fax) == 4000
fax.shape == (4000,)
type(fax) == <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

When I go to plot:

```
for i,j in enumerate(holders):
    ax.loglog(fax, j[i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: for i,j in enumerate(holders) -> j[i] is one single data point, isn't it? the full j would be one numpy array in the list? so, maybe you want holders[i] instead of j[i]?

Comment: @Shushiro That did it! Stupid mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of j[i] in the for-loop, use holders[i].

j[i] is one single data point, since j is one numpy array in your list of arrays. To access the numpy array, you need holders[i].